# "obvious url in rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, session, token

first off all please excuse me if i dont use all the right terminology. I have the URL issue with my rails app. Basically it works but I just find the url to be a bit too "obvious" and maybe a security issue.

example i have a user resource the users show page will go to websitename.com/users/user_id right ? This is probably convention but how do i go about changing that to display something random ? I tried using a secure token (not sure if it was the right thing to do) and sessions are saved in the token but the url is still quite obvious. Authorization works and non-signed in users cant just visit lets say user with id one lol. Please if this dosent make sense I will try and clarify just ask. Thanks.

Edit.
Also can some one explain to me what a token does then, my understanding was instead of saving a user session with the user id and the id hets displayed, a users session was saved in a secure token and the token (generally random string)  got displayed. wrong??

Comment: You can use `before_filter` to allow only signed users to visit any url.

Comment: @RamizRaja with CanCan it will be great :)

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier, It depends upon the complexity of application. If there are too many roles than CanCan with Device will be great! Otherwise simply using Device will be good enough.

Comment: thanks guys but i already have a before filter and it works, the user id in url just bugs me thats all. happy to see its not an issue on my part though :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method for your user object. You could then have i.e. a column in the database, where you store a hash that is your param for the object. See also the [Rails guides section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#to_param) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://rubygems.org/gems/friendly_id

It allows to have permalinks in urls instead of plain IDs